# How to add 20% noise of the maximum pixel intensity in an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, signal-processing

I have read an image and stored it in the NumPy array.

Let's say the image is stored in variable 'img'.

I know we add Gaussian noise based on the image as the standard deviation of the image. So, I write a function below.

```
def white_noise_2(sigma, n, mu=0):
    noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, n)
    return noise
```

where 'n' is the shape of the image and sigma is variance. I want to change or modify my function to add 20% noise in the image as the percentage of maximum intensity. How can we achieve this by modifying the function above?

Comment: So you want to use 20% of the image's maximum value as sigma?

Comment: I am not really sure about that. sigma is the variance of the image and it might not be correct to use 20% of that as the variance for noise signal.

Comment: So your question is *"how does '20% noise' relate to 'sigma'"*?

Comment: yes. Maybe that is a better way to put it. How does 20% noise of the maximum intensity relate to sigma?

Comment: That would rather be a math question than a programming question.

Comment: Sampling from normal distribution does not put any hard contstraints on the generated data; both very high and very low values are possible (low probability, but still possible). Using a different distribution with hard constraints (e.g. uniform) or clipping normal should solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Using uniform distribution (the function name implies this is the intent):

```
def white_noise_2(amplitude, n, mu=0):
    # amplitude is expected to be 20% of max intensity
    # can be obtained by `amplitude = image_array.max() * 0.2
    # don't forget to clip the output after adding to the image
    np.random.uniform(-amplitude, amplitude, n)
```

Clipping normal:

```
def white_noise_2(amplitude, n, mu=0):
    # clipping at 2 sigma, which covers ~95% of the data points,
    return np.clip(
        np.random.normal(0, amplitude / 2, n), -amplitude, amplitude)
```